# Meaning of the word "such"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> > Propositional logic approaches the discipline of logical thought on
> >     the basis of statements or propositions. This distinguishes it from
> >     earlier schools of logic, **such** Aristotle’s term-based logic.
>
> Stoicism: A Beginner's Guide To The History and Philosophy of Stoicism

Why did the author use the "such" there. I think It should have been "such as". Is it correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's typo.  It should be "such as".